# Use Dropbox access token without going through the authorization flow

Tags: c#, dropbox, dropbox-api

I've got a Generated access token from DropBox ".....fquCiA_pW5SsJal2C.......".

I'm using the following code to upload a file-

```
    static void Main()
    {
        // Uncomment the following line or manually provide a valid token so that you
        // don't have to go through the authorization process each time.
        //var accessToken =  GetAccessToken();
        // var accessToken = new OAuthToken("token", "secret");

        var api = new DropboxApi(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret, accessToken);
        var file = api.UploadFile("dropbox", @"myFolder\b.jpg", @"b.jpg"); 
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} uploaded.", file.Path));

    }
```

There is an instruction in the code that I can use a token. So, I have used-

```
var accessToken = "...lkasjdfsdlfjsadlj...";
```

But it shows invalid argument error. Where shall I use that key?

Please help?

I've taken the code from [here](http://cgeers.com/2012/03/11/dropbox-rest-api-part-5-file-upload/)

Comment: Can you post the full error/output you're getting? Also, what library and version of said library are you using (i.e., `DropboxApi`)?

Comment: @Gred, Link is there.